# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: app_commenti.sondaggio_id

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a school project. In this school project, I would like to create an application using Django. This application must allow to create pools, the users can vote and comment.
I created the models, I made the migration, and I issued the migrate command. Everething worked fine, but when I tried to add another foreign key in 'Commenti'  class, Django gave me problems. Now the `make migrations` command works fine, but when I run the `make migrate` command, I see an error.

Here is the code I have:

```py
from django.db import models

class Sondaggio(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    domanda = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_data = models.DateTimeField('data pubblicazione')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'scritto da {self.firstname} {self.lastname}-ID:{self.id}'
    
    
class Scelte(models.Model):
    sondaggio = models.ForeignKey(Sondaggio, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    scelta = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    voti = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'scelta di {self.firstname} {self.lastname}-id del sondaggio:{self.sondaggio_id}'
    
    
class Commenti(models.Model):
    sondaggio = models.ForeignKey(Sondaggio, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    commento = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    utilità = models.BooleanField(help_text='hai trovato interessante questo sondaggio?')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'scritto da {self.firstname} {self.lastname}'
```

Comment: Posting code as an image link makes it harder for us to help.  Please update the question to use just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget using command "makemigartions" and "migrate" after writing some models those models won't be applied in the database so you will be seeing this message as error
so please make and apply your migrations in order to have your database and models synced